# If we calculate the disparity values from SAD algorithm , how can we use that values to make the disparity map? what is the method?

Tags: c, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

If we calculate the disparity values from SAD algorithm , how can we use that disparity values to make the disparity map?  is their any method ?

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the Disparity Values using SAD algorithm, you get disparity values for each pixel. Let's suppose you have two images of dimensions: 100x100(image1) and 100x100(image2). when you compute your disparity values for these matrix the lets say you get output matrix as :

10 11 23 54.......9

10 12 22 65.......11

.

.

.

6 7 9 13..........2

which is again a 100x100 matrix. then this matrix is your matrix with values. to convert it into a disparity map you need to normalise your **min to max** disparity value in range of **0-255** for a grayscale disparity map. This will give you a graysacle disparity map. If you want to convert this disparity valued matrix to a coloured disparity map then do the same for R, G and B planes.

Hope this helps.